# C# / ConstructorParameter attribute

Tags: xaml, parameters, constructor

I've been writing some classes, that will be used inside window's XAML definition. I recall using an attribute called - AFAIR - ConstructorParameter, which informed XAML parser, that certain XML attributes corresponding to this property shall be treated as constructor parameters rather than property setters.

I've searched the Internet back and forth and I cannot find, which assembly this attribute belongs to. Can anyone help?

Best regards -- Spook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you would want to have a default constructor and a property for your extra value.

I found [this article](http://www.wpfwiki.com/Default.aspx?Page=WPF%20Q16.7&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) on wpfwiki.
...

> The typical XAML declarative syntax
>   always ends up creating objects using
>   their default constructor. Most of the
>   time, this is not a problem. However,
>   some classes have constructors taking
>   certain parameters, or simply don't
>   have a default constructor. In these
>   cases, it is still possible to declare
>   them in XAML using the
>   ObjectDataProvider class. The
>   following point of sale system code
>   snippet shows such a declaration in
>   the Window.Resources section.

```
<Window x:Class="WindowsApplication1.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System" 
        Title="ObjectDataProvider Sample"
        Height="300"
        Width="300"
    >
   <Window.Resources>
      <ObjectDataProvider ObjectType="{x:Type CornerRadius}"
                          x:Key="MyCornerRadius">
         <ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
            <system:Double>10.5</system:Double>
         </ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
      </ObjectDataProvider>
   </Window.Resources>

   <Grid>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyCornerRadius}, Path=TopLeft}"/>
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I found the attribute I was searching for and it was ConstructorArgument. However I quickly realized, that id doesn't do what I guessed it would and that I shall implement the parameterless constructor anyway - as you mentioned. Thanks for help!